# finding the newest file in the directory

Tags: bash, file

I need to find the newest file in the directory.
The line that I'm currently using is:

```
cd /mypath/ && ls -t | head -n1
```

The problem is that, I'm constantly creating files and sometimes, 
there are 2 files created at the '*same*' time, meaning that when I 
execute the line above I'll miss one of the files.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: `ls -lrt` will do it. (pipe to `tail -n1`) Or, for the filename only `ls -rt | tail -n1`

Comment: If you wanted a one-shot command to handle any path, then `fn="$(ls -rt /path/to/dir | tail -n1)"; echo "${fn##*/}"; unset fn`

Comment: David , i tried your suggestion . let me clear myself . i sample the directory each sec to get the latest file and retrive the data from it . the problem is that sometimes in this "1 sec" 2 files are being  created . and my next sample only gets 1 out of the 2 files ... so 1 file stays untouched

Comment: Rather than parsing the output of `ls`, I would recommend using `stat` - something along the lines of `stat -c "%Y %n" * | sort -n | tail -1`. Without resorting to Python or something similar, though, you're going to have a hard time doing this reliably if you have file names that might contain whitespace and other such oddities...

Comment: Twalberg, yeah that exactly what im doing .. there is a thread that runnig the ls command and then im parsing the specific file  using python . i dont get any problems when there is atleast an interval of 3 seconds between each ls command . the issue occurs when 2 files are created at the same time

Comment: As long as you're using Python anyway, `import stat` and use `stat.ST_MTIME`. That will be easier than parsing out `ls` separately.

Comment: maybe i should get at lest the 2 or 3 newest files just to make sure that i didnt miss any file ... using tail -2 or tail -3

Comment: That case is pretty much a stick wicket. If you have files with the same time, there is no way to discriminate between the two (or more) based on time. The only thing you can do is return the list of all of them at the same time. Let me work with `stat -c %Y` a bit and I'll let you know.

Comment: If you're on linux, you might want to look into inotifywait or incrond instead, to be able to trigger shell code whenever a file is written to.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the original mixup. Here is a short script that will find the newest file in a directory (given as the first argument). Use `stat -c %Y` to find its time in seconds since epoch. Then compare with all other files in the directory and if the time difference (`td`) is less than `10` seconds, output the filename (you can adjust the difference to meet your needs)

Give this a try:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="${1:-.}"  ## set path (default .)

[ "${path:(-1):1}" = '/' ] && path="${path%/}"  ## strip trailing '/'

oldifs="$IFS"   ## save old IFS, set to break on newline
IFS=$'\n'
fnarray=( $(ls -rt "$path" | tail -n5) )        ## read newest 5 into array
IFS="$oldifs"

for ((i=$((${#fnarray[@]} - 1)); i >= 0; i--)); do  ## make sure newest is file
    [ -f  "${path}/${fnarray[i]}" ] && fn="${path}/${fnarray[i]}" && break
done
[ -d "$fn" ] && { echo "error: no file found in newest 5 entries"; exit 1; }

for i in "${path}"/*; do                ## for each file in path
    [ -f "$i" ] || continue             ## if not a file skip
    td=$(( $(stat -c %Y "$i") - $(stat -c %Y "$fn") ))  ## time difference in sec
    (( td < 0 )) && td=$(( td * -1 ))   ## takes abs value
    (( td < 10 )) && echo "$i"          ## if less than 10 seconds, output file
done

exit 0
```

**Note:** the original issue I had was due to the possibility that the newest entry in the directory was a sub-directory (which was not wanted). This presented a challenge due to the way `ls ..| tail..` returned results. So basically I took the last 5 as a hack (you should set an initial try of 5, and if the `fn` is still a dir, increase it by twice and try again... until you have exhausted all files in the directory.. or do a simple `find /path/ -type f` first to insure there is a file present)  **Sigh**, but that would have completely obscured the test for oldest code.

The other issue I don't like with the solution is that comparing `stat` times is not inherently fast in bash. So this would not be lightning fast on large directories. (liveable with < 1000 entries). Returning the possible latest files with the exact same times is a good challenge with no quick off-the-shelf solution I could find.

---

### full script

A full implementation of iterative testing of all entries in the target directory working backwards from the newest to find the first file (not a dir) to compare times against would be something similar to the following. **note:** the code has been tested, but there may still be corner cases that need fixing:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="${1:-.}"          ## set path (default .)

[ "${path:(-1):1}" = '/' ] && path="${path%/}"  ## strip trailing '/'

[ -d "$path" ] || {     ## validate path
    echo "error: invalid path provided. '$path' not found."
    exit 1;
}

declare -i n=5      ## initial entries to read into array if fn is directory
declare -i oldn=1   ## save index for increased loop efficiency

## get number of files in target path
nfiles=$(wc -l < <( find "$path" -maxdepth 1 -type f ) )

(( $nfiles < 1 )) && {  ## test files present in path or exit
    echo "error: no files found in target directory"
    exit 1
}

oldifs="$IFS"   ## save old IFS, set to break on newline
IFS=$'\n'

fn="${path}/$(ls -rt "$path" | tail -n1)"        ## find most recent file

while [ -d "$fn" ]; do                           ## while fn is a directory
    fnarray=( $(ls -rt "$path" | tail -n$n) )    ## read newest n entries into array
    for ((i=$((${#fnarray[@]} - oldn)); i >= 0; i--)); do  ## make sure newest is file
        [ -f  "${path}/${fnarray[i]}" ] && fn="${path}/${fnarray[i]}" && break
    done
    (( n == nfiles )) && break                  ## if all entries tried, bail
    oldn=$n                                     ## update oldn to skip next try
    [ -f "$fn" ] && break || n=$(( n * 2 ))     ## if file, done, else n=n*2
    (( n > nfiles )) && n=nfiles                ## if n > nfiles, n=nfiles
done
[ -d "$fn" ] && {
    echo "error: something bad happened, no files found in target directory"
    exit 1
}
IFS="$oldifs"

for i in "${path}"/*; do                ## for each file in path
    [ -f "$i" ] || continue             ## if not a file skip
    td=$(( $(stat -c %Y "$fn") - $(stat -c %Y "$i") ))  ## time difference in sec
    (( td < 0 )) && td=$(( td * -1 ))   ## takes abs value
    (( td < 10 )) && echo "$i"          ## td less than X seconds, output filename
done

exit 0
```

Somehow this seems like overkill...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want not just the newest file, but you want to report each new file exactly once.  The following script does that, by keeping a `$reftime` file that tracks what it reported last time:

```
cd "$1"
reftime=/tmp/newest-file-name

next_file=
prev_file=$(cat "$reftime" 2> /dev/null)
while true; do
  read -r filename
  if [[ "$prev_file" ]]; then
    [[ "$filename" = "$prev_file" ]] && break # we've gotten to reported files
  else
    [[ -z "$filename" ]] && break # we've read past the last file
  fi
  next_file="$filename"
done < <(ls -t)

if [[ "$next_file" ]]; then
    # Update file $reftime with time and name of the file we're about to offer
    echo "$next_file" > "$reftime"
    touch -r "$next_file" "$reftime"

    echo "$next_file"
fi
```